# AngularJS ng-repeater not able to read json properly when API returns one object

Tags: json, api, parsing, angularjs-ng-repeat, response

I am studying **angularjs** and **web.api v2**
and to call a simple API to get list of Contacts, using below code:

```
   $scope.GetAllContacts = function () {
    $http.get('http://localhost:50820/api/contacts').
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.contacts = data;
        // OUT PUT WILL BE [{contact1},{contact2},....]
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("couldn't get contacts.");
    });
  }
```

each contact object has (ID,Name,Lastname,Email).

and this is my HTML page

```html
    <content ng-controller="ContactController">
        <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                <td>{{contact.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Email}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </content>
```

> Problem happens when API returns only 1 record, like {contact1} Like this {"Id":1,"Name":"James","LastName":"Oliver","Email":"james.oliver@gmail.com"}

at this point angularjs will treat it as a JSON object with 4 records, like this [{ID},{Name},{Lastname},{Email}]

and therefore Ng-Repeater is not able to find, contact.id , contact.name, contact.lastname or contact.email.

I am not sure, is it because of ASP.Net API returning wrong format, or I need to use another method ??

I have already tried JSON.parse and Angular.toJson but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue, I had two different method,

```
    GetAllContacts()  //returns a collection of contacts
    GetContact(int id) // return a single contact object
```

in fiddler both of the responses was OK, as they are detected as JSON object, but Ng-Repeater was taking the single object as a JSON with 4 object (because of 4 property), instead of treating it as one object.

so what I did, was to put the single contact object, in a collection and return the result as a collection with only one record. and It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check the data you are receiving in response from web service,inside the success function.

```
console.log(data);
```

if it print in below format then `ng-repeater` will be able to find the individual object.

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"James","LastName":"Oliver","Email":"james.oliver@gmail.com"}]
```

But if you receive the data like below.

```
{"Id":1,"Name":"James","LastName":"Oliver","Email":"james.oliver@gmail.com"}
```

Then `ng-repeater` won't be able to find it (May be you should check your server side then).

See i did a quick test at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/377/)